# Can a SwiftUI matchedGeometryEffect animation be combined with a transition?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, transition

I'd like to replace the default transition (`AnyTransition.opacity`) with another transition for a view that also has a `matchedGeometryEffect()` modifier applied. I've tried a couple different techniques, but none of them seem to accomplish this.

First, here's the `matchedGeometryEffect` on its own. The `ItemView` "moves" from one container to another, using the default animation.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace private var itemMovement
    @State private var isInFirst = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First Container")
            HStack {
                if isInFirst {
                    ItemView()
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "item", in: itemMovement)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .border(.red)
            
            Text("Second Container")
            HStack {
                if !isInFirst {
                    ItemView()
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "item", in: itemMovement)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .border(.red)
            
            Button("Move Item") {
                withAnimation {
                    isInFirst.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

[image: Implementation with default transitions and matchedGeometryEffect, Circle view animates from one container to the other]

Looking closely at the Circle, you can see that the color gets lighter at the middle of the animation. I believe this the effect of the default transition, `AnyTransition.opacity`. In an attempt to remove that transition, I tried to explicitly add an `AnyTransition.identity` on the Circle view.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace private var itemMovement
    @State private var isInFirst = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First Container")
            HStack {
                if isInFirst {
                    ItemView()
                        .transition(.identity) // <-- here
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "item", in: itemMovement)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .border(.red)
            
            Text("Second Container")
            HStack {
                if !isInFirst {
                    ItemView()
                        .transition(.identity) // <-- here
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "item", in: itemMovement)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .border(.red)
            
            Button("Move Item") {
                withAnimation {
                    isInFirst.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the result seems like the Circle view is no longer animating with the `matchedGeometryEffect`. I've tried a couple variations, such as placing the `.transition()` modifier after the `.matchedGeometryEffect()` modifier, and using the `.transition()` modifier on only one view at a time - hoping to understand why this jumping to the final position occurs and formulate a new solution. I haven't figured it out yet.

Can anyone help me figure out how to combine a transition with the matchedGeometryEffect? Outside of this simplified example, I'm hoping to create a custom transition, based on an animatable view modifier, which internally applies a `.rotation3DEffect()` to the view.

[image: Adding an explicit transition, the Circle view jumps to the final position instead of animating]

Comment: Replacing `.transition(.identity)` with `.transition(.scale(scale: 1))` achieves the moving of the circle without the color fading.

Comment: @vacawama good find, i tried and can verify that it works. any thoughts on how to explain this behavior, in contrast to `.transition(.identity)`? Does it depend on the coincidence that the size of both the views in each container are the same (so the scale factor of 1 agrees with the transform the matchedGeometryEffect is already adding)?

Comment: `.identity` does not provide an animatable value, so the view just pops in when added.  `.opacity` and `.scale` are animatable properties.  The `.opacity` fades a view in when it is added and fades it out when it is removed.  Your first example uses the default `.opacity` animation and so the first view is fading out as the second one is fading in.  By using `.scale`, the first view is being scaled up as the second view is being scaled down.  The value of `1` says that the view retains the same scale, so as the view is added, the view doesn't change size but is still animated.

Comment: @vacawama this explanation is sound, but its a bit hard to verify. How do we know `.identity` does not provide an animatable value while the others do? There doesn't seem to be any indication of this in docs. Also, it doesn't necessarily follow that the lack of an animatable value would lead to the view popping in, since (IIUC) the position and size of the view is being set by `matchedGeometryEffect`, and does not depend on the specifics of `.identity` or `.opacity` or any other transition. I'd like to understand how this works because then I can apply it while making my custom transition.

Answer (score 0):

This example appears to show a single circle "moving" from one container to another. In fact, it is showing two circles, where `matchedGeometryEffect` is being used to coordinate the positions and smooth the transition. The reason why you are observing a small color change is because the first circle is fading out at the same time as the second circle is fading in. If you look closely, the red borders of the HStacks and the label of the second container can also be seen under the circle shape while it is transitioning, because neither circle is opaque at the halfway point.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/matchedgeometryeffect(id:in:properties:anchor:issource:)) for `matchedGeometryEffect` states that results are undefined if "the number of currently-inserted views in the group with isSource = true is not exactly one". So if you really want to use `matchedGeometryEffect`, I would suggest you add `isSource: isInFirst` to the first case and `isSource: !isInFirst` to the second case. However, even if you fix the fade issue by using a `.scale` transition (as explained in an earlier comment), you will probably still face difficulties when it comes to implementing the `.rotation3DEffect` that you described in your question. This is because the effect will not be animated if you are transitioning between two separate views.

So instead of using `matchedGeometryEffect`, another way to implement the animation would be to apply the change in position to a single circle. Something like this:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First Container")
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    if isInFirst {
                        ItemView().hidden()
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .border(.red)

                Text("Second Container")
                HStack {
                    if !isInFirst {
                        ItemView().hidden()
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .border(.red)
            }
            .overlay(alignment: isInFirst ? .top : .bottom) {
                ItemView().padding()
            }
            Button("Move Item") {
                withAnimation {
                    isInFirst.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Things to notice:

- there is now only one visible circle, this is shown in an overlay
- hidden placeholders are used to reserve space for the visible circle in the two alternative positions
- since it really is the same circle that is changing position, there is no fade effect and the circle remains opaque at all times
- `matchedGeometryEffect` is not needed at all
- if you were to apply a `rotation3DEffect` to the moving view (as you were describing), this would be animated smoothly too.

*EDIT* Following from your comment, your best bet might be a combination of the two approaches:

- apply the animated changes to a single view (which could be an overlay, or a layer in a `ZStack`)
- control its position using `matchedGeometryEffect`
- the source to be matched could be the containers themselves
- use hidden placeholders to resesrve space as before.

This way, you should be able to animate the rotation effect too. Here it is working:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace private var itemMovement
    @State private var isInFirst = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("First Container")
                HStack {
                    if isInFirst {
                        ItemView().hidden()
                    }
                }
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "frame1", in: itemMovement, isSource: isInFirst)
                .padding()
                .border(.red)

                Text("Second Container")
                HStack {
                    if !isInFirst {
                        ItemView().hidden()
                    }
                }
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "frame2", in: itemMovement, isSource: !isInFirst)
                .padding()
                .border(.red)

                Button("Move Item") {
                    withAnimation {
                        isInFirst.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
            ItemView()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: isInFirst ? "frame1" : "frame2",
                    in: itemMovement,
                    isSource: false
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this solution is a great workaround, and it will likely work for a large set of use cases. However, in my use case the two views are in separate containers and I'd like to keep it that way. The common ancestor is way up the view tree, and it would be strange to add some `.overlay()` to that parent and nearly impossible to track the right position through the views/layouts in between (PreferenceKeys are tricky).

Comment: OK, answer updated with a solution that combines the two approaches.